# $_Post registration with variable return on registration status

Tags: php, mysql, select

So I'm trying to make a registration page that feeds back a variable when a certain flag is raised.. "All ready registered" "Registration limit" IS this the best way to do this or is there a better way? I'm a little new to PHP...I keep getting an error on the mysql_num_rows()..

Here is the code....

```
<?php
//not really
$dbhost = 'sample';
$dbname = 'contacts';
$dbuser = 'sample';
$dbpass = 'sample';
//retrieve our data from POST
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass1 = $_POST['password'];
$pass2 = $_POST['timestamp'];
$pass3 = $_POST['deviceId'];
$pass4 = $_POST['phone'];
$pass5 = $_POST['name'];


$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
        mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

//sanitize username
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$pass1 = mysql_real_escape_string($pass1);
$pass2 = mysql_real_escape_string($pass2);
$pass3 = mysql_real_escape_string($pass3);
$pass4 = mysql_real_escape_string($pass4);
$pass5 = mysql_real_escape_string($pass5);

function email_exists()
{
   // $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '" . $username . "'";
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username = '" . $username . "'");
        // $sql2 = mysql_db_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '" . $username . "'");
        // $erg = mysql_num_rows($sql2) > 0;
    return (mysql_num_rows($sql2)); //method 1
}

function device_exists()
{

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE deviceID = '" . $pass3 . "'";
    //$sql2 = mysql_db_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE deviceID = '" . $pass3 . "'");

    $sql3 = mysql_query($query2);
    return (mysql_num_rows($sql3)); //method 2
}

if (email_exists() == 0) {
    //(passed the no email in database, now lets check how many accounts under the device ID)
    if (device_exists() < 3) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO Users ( username, password, timestamp, deviceId, phone, name )
        VALUES ( '$username' , '$pass1' , '$pass2', '$pass3', '$pass4', '$pass5');";
        mysql_query($query);
        mysql_close();
        echo "1"; // Regstered succefully
    } else {
        echo "5"; //3 registered users per device only
    }
} else {
    echo "0"; //already have an account (email is used.....)
}

?>
```

Comment: what error mysql_num_rows() giving ?

Comment: Plz share what err u r getting !

Comment: Well now its stopped givig me the error, but it still always returns 0... even if the account is not in there.. or it is. Am i calling the functions right? am i using the function output correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have may be [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619513/if-statement-not-recognising-when-mysql-num-rows-returns-0-results) problem
Hello please try with the greaterthan operator (>) with zero

```
if ( email_exists()) // valid result
{
    if ( email_exists() > 0 ) // more than 0 records
        // rest code;
    else
       // insert operation;
}
```

Thanks... best luck

Comment: let me know what problem phase in this solution ?

Comment: I figured it out but thanks everyone...Sometimes you just need someone to bounce ideas with..

Comment: no problem...let me know if you have any issue with this in future...have great time ahead :)